# I need help with a competition math problem please.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am a competition math student, and I was doing a practice test when I found this problem:
"The fourth degree polynomial equation $x^4 - 7x^3 + 4x^2 + 7x - 4 = 0$ has four real roots a, b, c and d. What is the value of the sum $1/a + 1/b + 1/c + 1/d$? Express your answer as a common fraction."
First of all, I don't think this polynomial can be factored, so I don't know how to find the reciprocals of the roots. I need help and any help would be appreciated! Note: When they say "Express your answer as a common fraction.", it means that the answer IS a fraction. I tried asking this question already, but I worded it differently, and they didn't get a fraction so I knew it was wrong. This is the link to my other question: [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091605/solving-a-polynomial-with-grouping)

Comment: You may find [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) useful.

Comment: Make the substitution $y=1/x$ and consider the quartic in $y$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3091605/solving-a-polynomial-with-grouping)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It isn't a duplicate. Read my edit.

Comment: The answer there has been corrected now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a polynomial $f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots +a_0$ with roots $r_1,r_2,\dots, r_n$. We claim that the polynomial with roots $\frac{1}{r_1},\frac{1}{r_2},\dots,\frac{1}{r_n}$ is simply $g(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\dots + a_n$.  Why? Because if you observe that the roots of the polynomial $f(\frac{1}{x})$ are the reciprocals of the roots of $f(x)$, then our desired polynomial is $$\begin{align*}g(x)&=x^nf(1/x)\\&=x^n\left(\frac{a_n}{x^n}+\frac{a_{n-1}} {x^{n-1}}+\cdots+\frac{a_1}{x}+a_0\right)\\&=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n,\end{align*}$$

The desired polynomial can be found by simply 'reversing the coefficients' as shown above. Hence the polynomial with roots $\frac{1}{a},\frac 1b, \frac 1c,$ and $\frac 1d$  is $$-4x^4+7x^3+4x^2-7x+1$$ Applying Vieta's Formulae to this, we find that the sum of the roots is $-\frac{-7}{4}=\frac{7}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks! I got 7/4 too because my reasoning was that $x^4 p(1/x) = -4x^4+7x^3+4x^2-7x+1$ and the sum of the roots is $-7/-4=7/4$. I just wasn't 100% sure that you could do this.

Comment: @Spencer1O1 nice work! In the future, consider tagging your competition math questions with the tag [contest-math]

Comment: Okay! I tried to tag it with [competition-math], but it didn't exist. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to write
$$
\frac{1}{a}+
\frac{1}{b}+
\frac{1}{c}+
\frac{1}{d}=\frac{bcd+acd+abd+abc}{abcd}
$$
write $f(x)=x^4-7x^3+4x^2+7x-4=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$ and use [Vieta's  relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

For example, by multiplying out we see at once that  $abcd=-4$ and $-(bcd+acd+abd+abc)=7.$